# Ruby Prime Factors

Tags: ruby, prime-factoring

I've seen solutions posted in other languages but not Ruby so I'm asking here.

Trying to find out the largest prime factor of 13195.

My code is as follows

```
    # find out all numbers that divide without remainder into 13195

    array = []
    count = 2

    13195.times do 
        if 13195 % count == 0
            array.push(count)   
        end
        count += 1
    end



    #From those numbers that divide cleanly into 13195, find out which are prime aka can only be divided by themselves and 1

    new_count = 2
    primes = 0

    array.each do |x|
        while new_count < x 
            if x % new_count != 0
            else
                if x > primes
                primes = x
            end
            end
        new_count += 1
        end
    end

     puts primes
```

In my first loop I am populating an empty array with all the numbers that divide into 13195 without a remainder, from testing this piece of code seems to be working.

It's the second part of my solution that's the problem inside my each statement, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second loop can be re-written to do what is meant to do.

As I understand, your goal is to select from `array`, largest of such elements that are prime (divides by only 1 and itself).  In other words, an element `x` is eligible if it is not divisible by any number between `2` and `x-1`.

```
result = array.select {|x| not (2..x-1).any? {|i| x % i  == 0} }.max
#=> 29
```

---

Currently, your logic has some flaws.  It is not resetting the value of `new_count` and hence you are getting wrong results.  Here is corrected version:

```
array.each do |x|
    is_prime = true
    while new_count < x 
        if x % new_count == 0
            is_prime = false
        end
        new_count += 1
    end
    new_count = 2
    primes = x if is_prime and x > primes
end
```

Comment: Perfect. I've used select and any before but I never would have thought to combine them like that. Looks like I have a long way to go. Cheers!

Comment: @Sevenum Welcome to StackOverflow!  Don't [forget to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped.

Comment: Thanks, what a great place. I was wondering since I consider what you gave to be an advanced answer, if it could be done using an each and an if like I attempted originally?

Comment: @Sevenum It can be done, your current loop logic is not correct -  I have updated the answer

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you use [Prime#prime_division](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division):

```
require 'prime'

def largest_prime_factor(n)
  Prime.prime_division(n).max_by(&:first).first
end

largest_prime_factor(13195)
  #=> 29

(1..1000).to_a.sample(15).sort.each {|n| puts "%3d: %3d" % [n, largest_prime_factor(n)]}
 61:  61
 80:   5
 88:  11
250:   5
304:  19
414:  23
514: 257
548: 137
679:  97
716: 179
754:  29
770:  11
906: 151
907: 907
968:  11
```

For example,

```
n = 13195
a = Prime.prime_division(n)
  #=> [[5, 1], [7, 1], [13, 1], [29, 1]] 
b = a.max_by(&:first)
  #=> [29, 1] 
b.first
  #=> 29
```

It appears that the elements of the array returned by `prime_division` are in order of increasing prime factor. If that were guaranteed, one could just write:

```
Prime.prime_division(n).last.first
```

I used `max_by` in the event that the order of those elements is implementation-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version:

```
require 'prime'
primes = Prime.each(13195).to_a
upper = primes.last
```

`primes` will have all primes from 0 to 13195 and upper obviously the last.

Comment: It's not the largest prime up to 13195 that's wanted, it's the largest prime factor of 131195.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right, I did not read properly, is the "tree" of factors what its  wanted

Answer (score 1):

I set a limit of prime numbers to 100000 (to avoid of couple days of calculation of big numbers like 600851475143 =) )

```
def prime_factors(n)
  prime_array = []    
  p = 2
  if n < 2
      return p
  end


  while p < n && p < 1000000
    if n % p == 0
      prime_array.push(p)
    end
  p +=1
  end

  primes = []

  prime_array.size.times do |i|
    if n > 1
      n = n / prime_array[i]
      primes.push(prime_array[i])
    end
  end
  return primes.last
end

#prime_factors(600851475143)
puts prime_factors(600851475143)

#prime_factors(13195)
puts prime_factors(13195)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use prime_division:

```
require 'prime'
(13195).prime_division.map(&:first).max
=> 29
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using [Prime#prime_division](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division) we can dived the problems into small parts. the first part if to write a method that determine whether a number if prime or not, which can be like :

```
def prime?(num)

    if num < 2
        return false
    end
   (2...num).each do |ele|
      if num % ele == 0 
        return false
      end
   end
  return true
end
```

then we can write our main method which is asking for the prime_factors of a number like:

```
def prime_factors(num)

prime_facts = []

(1..num).each do |i|
    if  num % i == 0 && prime?(i)
        prime_facts << i
    end
end
return prime_facts
end 

print prime_factors(24) #=> [2, 3]
puts
print prime_factors(60) #=> [2, 3, 5]
puts
print prime_factors(13195) # [5, 7, 13, 29]
puts
```